# Retrieve list of defined roles in java ee 5

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee

I was wondering if it would be possible to retrieve the complete list of security roles defined in a web.xml file in the java code? And if so how to do it?

I am aware of the 'isUserInRole' method but I also want to handle cases where a role is requested but not defined (or spelled differently) in the web.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way do do this within the Servlet API.  However, you can parse web.xml directly and extract the values yourself.  I used dom4j below, but you can use whatever XML processing stuff you like:

```
protected List<String> getSecurityRoles() {
    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
    InputStream is = sc.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/web.xml");

    try {
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        Document doc = reader.read(is);

        Element webApp = doc.getRootElement();

        // Type safety warning:  dom4j doesn't use generics
        List<Element> roleElements = webApp.elements("security-role");
        for (Element roleEl : roleElements) {
            roles.add(roleEl.element("role-name").getText());
        }
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return roles;
}
```

Comment: too bad the container offers no way to get that info, but this seems like a fine workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version of Ian's answer using newer DOM API:

```
private List<String> readRoles() {
    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    InputStream is = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/web.xml");

    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(is));

        NodeList securityRoles = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("security-role");
        for (int i = 0; i < securityRoles.getLength(); i++) {
            Node n = securityRoles.item(i);
            if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                NodeList roleNames = ((Element) n).getElementsByTagName("role-name");
                roles.add(roleNames.item(0).getTextContent().trim()); // lets's assume that <role-name> is always present
            }
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Exception while reading security roles from web.xml", e);
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.warn("Exception while closing stream", e);
            }
        }
    }

    return roles;
}
```